# How to write regular expression with format "[12,23][12,23]"?

Tags: html, regex, pattern-matching

I am struggling in this issue.

Target format should be `[12,23][12,23]` or `[234,324][34,324]` they all legally.
just like `[int,int][int,int]`

I confused with this regular expression with Symbol `[` and `]`

BTW, I am using this in HTML5, trying to restrict user input.
Thanks in advances!

Comment: Escape the brackets to match them literally. `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: Try `(?:\[\d+,\d+\]){2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backslash (\) to escape special characters. Here is a test page you may use: https://www.regexpal.com/ The first part of your expression will look like:

```
/\[[0-9]{2,3},[0-9]{2,3}\]/
```